# After restoring from Time Capsule, a "Reset Password" button appears on the login screen

Tags: time-machine, backup, restore, password, time-capsule

After sending my MacBook Pro out for repairs, I got it back as a factory reset, so I had to go through the process of restoring from my Time Capsule. After completing the restore, there's now a new "Reset Password" button on the login screen that I swear wasn't there before. I'm afraid to click the button and mess things up, so I just want to know: if someone were to get a hold of my laptop and click that button, would they have to enter the current password before they could reset it? It makes me nervous that that button is there. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: You got the machine from a "factory reset" and then completely restored from TM. The Mac "knows" it's been revived, but the credentials do not match. I would push the button and set the password to whatever you want and you will never see that thing again. I had a similar situation before (but this was a few years ago and do not remember the exact details, so whatever you do, the usual recommendations apply: do it at your own risk, make sure your TM backup is still good to go in case you have to re-recover, etc).

Comment: @cucu8 I think that should be an answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will move it, I did not want to abuse the system (although I love the points that maybe incoming :-) ) using my comment to harvest fame what I felt was an indication rather than a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should push the button and set the password to whatever you like.

Since the machine was "factory reset" (as per yours) and then you dropped the TM backup on top of the reset, she/he/it now has non-matching credentials and is asking you to set things right.

Do all this under the usual precautions: own risk, make sure your backup is good and usable in case you have to repeat the process, etc.